# HttpClient object method missing

Tags: c#

I am separating some code out of a website and after copying the code behind for the particular page in question, I'm getting an error on the `PostAsJsonAsync()` line of code:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/...", user);
```

which is in this using statement (added headers as well)

```
        using System;
        using System.Net.Http;
        using System.Net.Http.Headers;
        using System.Net.Mail;
        using System.Threading.Tasks;
        //...

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("WebServiceAddress");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/...", user);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                const string result = "Thank you for your submission.";
                return result;
            }
            //...
        }
```

The error I get says

```
 Error  4   'System.Net.Http.HttpClient'
 does not contain a definition for 'PostAsJsonAsync' and no extension
 method 'PostAsJsonAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient'
 could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

even though it works in the former project and was copied straight over from that project in its entirety. Did I forget to add something?

I appreciate any help on the matter.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You will have to add following dependency,

```
System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll
```

It should be there in extensions -> assembly.

or

You can add `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` nuget package

Comment: Bingo. I'll mark this as the answer as soon as it allows me.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote my own extension method as I believe that method is only for older .NET api, and used Newtonsoft JSON serializer:

```
// Extension method to post a JSON
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsJsonAsync(this HttpClient client, string addr, object obj)
{
    var response = await client.PostAsync(addr, new StringContent(
            Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj),
            Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, even with the respective Nuget package installed. What helped me is just this `using` statement:

```
using System.Net.Http;
```

Comment: For me the package worked only after reinstall, however, this using statement is already in answer, so this is not an answer.